# How to dynamically update parameters of an existing Airflow (1.9 version)Connection within code?

Tags: ssh, airflow

I have defined a SSH connection via Airflow Admin UI. However I am only defining a service account , host and port in the UI. I am retrieving the password in the first task instance and I need to update the SSH connection with the password in the second task instance and use it in the third task instance.

- t1 : call an R function to retrieve password for svc account (stored
  in xcom_push)
- t2 : Update the SSH connection with this password (I am using
  SSHHook) ssh02.password = password (retrieved via xcom_pull)
- t3 : call a server using previously updated connection (ssh02)

Currently t1 and t2 work as expected ,however t3 fails since the password is not getting updated and it is looking for `.ssh` key file based authentication. Can someone please suggest how this can be implemented ?

Here is my code snippet :

```
    from airflow import models
    from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
    from airflow.models import Variable
    from airflow.models import Connection
    from airflow.settings import Session
    from airflow.utils import db
    from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
    from airflow import DAG
    import logging
    import os

    svcpassword = 'XXXX'

    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


    ssh01 = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='ssh_conn1')
    ssh02 = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='ssh_conn2')


    default_args = {
     'owner': 'user',
     'depends_on_past': False,
     'start_date': datetime.now(),
     'email': ['abcd@gmail.com'],
     'email_on_failure': True,
     'email_on_retry': True,
     'retries': 1,
     'retry_delay':timedelta(minutes=1)
  }


   dag = DAG('dag_POC', default_args=default_args, 
   schedule_interval="@once")

   path1 = '/home/user/R_samplescript'


   t1 = SSHOperator(
        task_id='SSHTask',
        command='Rscript '+path1+'.R',
        ssh_hook=ssh01,
        params={},retries =1 ,
        do_xcom_push = True,
        dag = dag
      )

  def create_new_connection(**kwargs):
       ti = kwargs['ti']
       pwd = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='SSHTask')
       password = str(pwd).replace("\\n","\n")
       password = password[password.find(' ')+1 : ]
       password = password.strip()
       svcpassword = password
       db.merge_conn( models.Connection(
                   conn_id='ssh_conn2', conn_type='SSH',
                    host='server_name', port='XXXX',login = 
                   'account_name',password = svcpassword))


        t2 = PythonOperator(
                task_id='Create_Connection',
                python_callable=create_new_connection,
                provide_context=True,
                dag=dag
                )


          t3 = SSHOperator(
                  task_id='RemoteCallTest',
                  command="R command",
                  ssh_hook = SSHHook().get_conn('ssh_conn2'),
                  do_xcom_push = False,
                  retries = 1,
                  dag=dag
             )



          t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Comment: in the future please provide code examples as it would make this easier to answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to leverage the session wrapper to persist changes to the db

```
@provide_session()
def set_password(session=None):
    conn = MyHook().get_conn(conn_id)
    conn.set_password(my_password)

    session.add(conn)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: I updated my code to use the merge_conn function (from airflow.utils.db.py ). But still the SSH connection in t3 fails. :-(

Comment: @tpatole If you don't use the code example from this answer (and use a `commit`) the changes will not be saved to the database.

Comment: I was able to ressolve this by replacing the merge_conn call by code below :        session = Session()
         ssh02 = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='ssh_conn2')
         Conn1 = 
         session.query(models.Connection).filter(models.Connection.conn_id 
                                  == ssh02.ssh_conn_id).first()
         Conn1.set_password(svcpassword)
         ssh02 = session.merge(Conn1)
         session.commit()
         session.close()

Comment: from airflow import DAG, settings; session = settings.Session()